# How to enhance the App in terms of speed, size and performance

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent

I want to minimise the size and improve the speed of my app.

Will it be better to Inflate different layout in same activity rather than creating activity with separate XML Layout and opening them via Intent.

As I think Creating activities with separate layout will need to be process more
and create stack overhead. In another case only one time activity will be loaded and only layout will be inflated to access its element, will it benefit in terms of speed and performance.

Suppose If i have two layout and I am inflating it in same activity at runtime, 
will be benificial

or using Frgment will improve in terms of Size Speed and Performance.

or calling the Normal Activity with seprate layout via Intent is well and good.

```
public void met1(View v)
    {

        setContentView(R.layout.content2);

        View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.content2, null);
       // builder.setView(customView);
        Button dialogTitle = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.text2);

        dialogTitle.setAllCaps(true);
        Log.e("*****", String.valueOf(dialogTitle.getText()));
    }

    public void met2(View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    }
```

Comment: why don't you test both options on your own? This way you'll get your own experience, and it will be much more usefull then just folowing somebody's advice. I think that not only performance and app size matters, but also the code readability and maintainability does. It would be much harder to maintain the code if it all is written in one class (one activity)

Comment: If you want to switch between views - you probably should cache views and make 'setContentView' only once, than just change views via add\remove view from layout

Answer (score 1):

A good software is where following things are balanced

1. Usability of software
2. Architecture
3. Code quality
4. Testing
5. Software Size

Now if you see for me application size comes last. Going with the single activity will have less stack operations but it increases the code in activity class, in longer run its not maintainable.

Also irrespective of number of activities OS has to take pain of inflating layouts.

By keeping everything in activity you have problem with testing (Unit Testing).

I would still suggest you go with Activities and Fragments , and along with that use MVP design pattern or Clean Architecture.

There are some ways where you can really get the work done with Single Activity but I am bit biased with the approach which I put above this line.

Comment: To handle or switch between layout at runtime will be better with Fragment rather than  Activity in terms of memory ,scalability and speed , rather than mentioning new Activity in manifest as it take much afford to process bla bla.. As I think. please suggest me that less activity and more Fragment will be better or not for the point you mentioned above.

Comment: One activity more fragment also means more fragment life cycle issue.Pne can not say Less activity more fragment is better or more activity less fragment is better. It depends on how your views and requirement are? What kind of treatment they require in terms of life cycle events, refresh rate etc. Its all about balancing.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this](https://realm.io/news/sf-fabien-davos-modern-android-ditching-activities-fragments/) article can answer your questions. There you can find information about single activity architecture and example how to implement it in your app.